# ошибка triggerUncaughtException node js telegram-api

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> node:internal/process/promises:246
> triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
> ^

```
const TelegramApi = require('node-telegram-bot-api')

const bot = new TelegramApi(token, {polling:true})
const chats = {}


const start = async () => {

    bot.setMyCommands([
        {command: '/start', description: 'Начальное приветствие'},
        {command: '/pay', description: 'Купить ключ'},
        {command: '/game', description: 'Игра угадай цифру'}
    ])

}

bot.on('message', async msg => {
    const text = msg.text
    const chatId = msg.chatId

    if(text === "/start") {
        await bot.sendMessage(chatId, `123 ${text}`)
    }
})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: async/await убери

Comment: @Rudi добавил еще одну картинку. убрал асинк, но когда пишу боту /start выдает ошибку.

Comment: const chatId = msg.from.id;